# MySQL - Getting all data in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have recently been doing some PHP scripting and need to know how to select all of a table. I have tried searching this up for about an hour and cannot find a source that works.(MySQL version 5.5.24)
I am trying to select a table, then list all data for that table. This is what I have so far.

```
<?php
$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = '';
$db_database    = 'friends';
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db($db_database);

    if (file_exists("C:/wamp/www/minebook/index.php")) {

    $rank = "1";
    $name = "HeyThatMan";
    $flpserver = "Google. We know everything about you :)";
    $flpsversion = "UNKNOWN";

    $writestring = '
    <tr>
    <td class="frank">'.$rank.'</td>
    <td class="fname">'.$name.'</td>
    <td class="flpserver">'.$flpserver.'</td>
    <td class="flpsversion">'.$flpsversion.'</td>
    </tr>
    ';
    $file = fopen("C:/wamp/www/minebook/friends/friends.php", "a");
    echo str_replace("abcdef",$writestring,"abcdef");
    }

        ?>
```

Now where I defined the variables, $rank, $name, $flpserver, and $flpsversion, I need to get those from the actual database table(Database: friends, Table: list). I have tried doing so for about an hour but failed each time. This is what I tried:

```
$rank = mysql> SELECT * FROM list WHERE rank = "1";
```

Now, it gives me an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'list' (T_LIST) in C:\wamp\www\minebook\friends\friends.php on line 49
```

Whats wrong with the code I am doing?

Comment: Show us your `friends.php` code.

Comment: Where are your `mysql_query()` and `mysql_fetch_assoc()` which will read the information from your database?

Comment: You should use MYSQLI

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
$rank = mysql> SELECT * FROM list WHERE rank = "1";
```

can't run!

You probably meant to do:

```
$rank = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE rank = '1';");
```

Comment: don't use mysql_query, use MySQLi - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php